# How to access the users details in different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, one-to-many

I have created a user portfolio react app. This app has authentication so that only logged in users can see: registered users + their portfolios. In my App.js component, I am storing the props of user. In my Portfolio component which is named 'Folio'. I am able to access the logged in users id with the following variable, `this.props.match.params.id` and it displays the logged in users ID.
I am wondering how I would access the users name or email this way.
After many attempts I seem to only be able to access the users ID

Here is the code from App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {loggedIn: false, user: {email: '', name:''}};
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

  logout(props) {
    axios.get('api/logout')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({loggedIn: false});
        props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch( err => console.log(err));
    return null;
  }

  login(user) {

    this.setState({loggedIn: true, user: user});
  }
```

Here is the Folio Component. Notice how I can access the users id with `this.props.match.params.id` but I cannot access the name or email.

```
export default class Folio extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      folio: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Howdy ' + `${this.props.match.params.id}`);
    console.log('Howdy ' + `${this.props.user.name}`);
    axios.get(`/api/users/${this.props.match.params.id}/folios`)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({folio: response.data});
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

I am only adding `:id` to the route

```
  <Link to={`/folio/${this.props.id}`}>
        <button className="button is-link" type="button">
              View Portfolios
        </button>
      </Link>

  <Route path="/folio/:id" render={(props) => <Folio {...props} user={this.state.user}/>} />
```

However I am looking for the name as well.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you. `match.params.id` will get the value of the `:id` path property in e.g. `/path/to/:id`. Do you have `:email` and `:username` in the path as well?

Comment: Hi sorry about that I am new to SO. I have added to the summary above, I'm only using :id at the end of the path. When I add :name i get an error. What syntax would you use for passing :id and :name to the path? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should pass them down to the component like you did with the `id` and you should access them the same way e.g => `this.props.match.params.name`. I guess you're passing only the ids to the component.